# Is it possible to make a macOS app accessible via Status menu?

Tags: menu-bar

Is there any way to place a macOS app in Status bar which does not originally have a Status bar component? Is there any simple app which can make this conversion for any macOS app?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Your question reads as if you have a solution and want a way to implent it (see [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

No. Unless the developer of the app has programmed it to show in Menu bar, it is not possible to do so.

There's no tool which can do this for you.